# Query for multiple possible IDs in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a web site using asp.net, and I have been tasked with providing a histogram of data stored in a SQL server.

The information I need is stored in a table like this:

```
Date | Value | Machine_ID
--------------------------
04   | 102   | 1
05   | 105   | 1
06   | 106   | 1
04   | 103   | 2
05   | 103   | 2
06   | 185   | 2
04   | 100   | 3
05   | 99    | 3
06   | 182   | 3
```

The issue I'm running into is this - sometimes we want to view the values for all the machines, usually on a graph normalized to 100% (used for viewing trends, like "we didn't produce as much in total in the month of May") which is just a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Mode_History
```

And sometimes we want to view the history for just one machine, which is also easy:

```
SELECT * FROM Mode_History WHERE (Machine_ID = ?)
```

But, my goal is to allow the end user to select multiple machines, and view the data for all of them combined together over the past few days.  If I were just writing the query, it would basically be:

```
SELECT * FROM Mode_History WHERE (Machine_ID = 100) OR (Machine_ID = 102)
```

But, I don't know how to achieve something similar in asp.net.

I've tried creating data-bound listbox controls, and enabling multiple selection then using their value as a parameter in the query, but that only returns the first item selected.  I've also tried Google-ing for the answer, but I'm not quite sure how to phrase the question.

So, my question is: What is the best way to achieve this in asp.net? I work primarily in C#, so I would really appreciate an answer in C#. I understand VB well enough to convert it though.

Comment: I've mostly used a comma delimited list of numbers, then appended that to a query's `WHERE` clause with the `IN` operator.  Just be careful of any escaping since you likely won't be able to use parametrized queries.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wound up doing.  I'm a bit worried about SQL Injection attacks, but honestly this is being run on the Company Intranet, so I'm thinking that it won't be too exposed to attackers.  I'm going to keep researching to see if I can use parameters as well.

Comment: You should always worry about injection.  Personally, I feel escaping is a viable alternative to parameters in some situations, but it must always be used extremely carefully.

Comment: @user2494447 So long as you have _complete control_ over the list you should be safe from injection attacks - e.g. if you create the string from a list of integers (rather than direct user input) you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular approach would be assembling the desired SQL query in the code behind when according to your scenario changes.

Comment: This is what I wound up doing.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best approach will be the following

1) You need send the user selection in comma separated way as a param in SQL server.
(ex: "100,200")

2) You need to create a stored procedure with the following

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(500) = '100,200'
DECLARE @UINPUT AS TABLE
(
    value INT
)

INSERT INTO @UINPUT 
SELECT PART FROM dbo.Split(@input,',')

-- GET THE RESULT
SELECT * 
FROM Mode_History AS MH
JOIN @UINPUT AS UN
ON   MH.Machine_ID = UN.value
```

3) The user defined split function is below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
   @sString nvarchar(2048),
   @cDelimiter nchar(1)
)
RETURNS @tParts TABLE ( part nvarchar(2048) )
AS
BEGIN
IF @sString IS NULL RETURN

DECLARE     @iStart INT,
            @iPos INT
IF SUBSTRING(@sString,1,1) = @cDelimiter 
BEGIN
    SET     @iStart = 2
    INSERT INTO @tParts
    VALUES(NULL)
END
ELSE 
    SET @iStart = 1
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SET @iPos = CHARINDEX(@cDelimiter,@sString,@iStart)
    IF @iPos = 0
        SET @iPos = LEN(@sString)+ 1
    IF @iPos - @iStart > 0                  
        INSERT INTO @tParts
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@sString,@iStart,@iPos-@iStart))
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @tParts
        VALUES(NULL)
    SET @iStart = @iPos+1
    IF @iStart > LEN(@sString) 
        BREAK
end
RETURN

END
```

Comment: `One of the Best`...? this looks to be a very long approach to doing something

Comment: Also, I'm not too familiar with SQL, but this appears to be a method of implementing the 'IN' operator yourself...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility if you don't mind not having parametrized queries (safe for int):

```
SELECT * FROM Mode_History WHERE Machine_ID IN (100, 102)
```

Here, the "100, 102" can be appended to the query string as a variable.

Alternatively if you want parameters, use a string variable:

```
SELECT * FROM Mode_History WHERE ',100,102,' LIKE '%,' + Machine_ID + ',%'
-- SELECT * FROM Mode_History WHERE @ParamString LIKE '%,' + Machine_ID + ',%'
```

Here, the single string ',100,102,' can be replaced with a parameter.  It's still combining multiple parameters into one string object but it should provide some level of safety against injection attacks.

Comment: I did try doing something similar to that, but the sql data source class kept detecting that Machine_ID was a int and tried to convert '102, 103' to a single int.

Comment: @user2494447 I'm pretty sure there's an extended format for query parameters where you can specify which SQL or object type they should be.  In this case, you'd just want something like `VARCHAR(255)` or equivalent.  (ie: when you create `SelectParameter` make sure to set its Type)